# Insert closing tags before opening tags with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like this in my html:

```
<ol>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li><span id="cursor"></span></li>
<li></li>
</ol>
```

I want to split the list in 2 at cursor with js adding

```
</li></ol><ol><li>
```

so the result is this:

```
<ol>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ol>
<ol>
<li><span id="cursor"></span></li>
<li></li>
</ol>
```

I have tried this:

```
cursor.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '</li></ol><ol><li>')
```

This doesn't work because the closing tags from the beginning get ignored and the open ol and li elements are getting closed.
Can somebody help me achieve this?

Comment: You start with one OL that has **4** LI children, but in the end you have a total of **5** LI children, spread over two OL parents. Is that correct, and if so what rules are used to determine the creation of an additional LI child?

Comment: *I have tried this* - the issue here is that you are thinking you are manipulating an HTML *string* - you are not.  You are inserting into the DOM.  The DOM is not HTML (it is generated by HTML, but it is no longer HTML).  As such, you can't insert `</li>` as it's not valid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this using `insertAdjacentHTML`.

What you can do instead is to create a new list, iterate through the child elements of the first list and move all the items before the one that contains `span#cursor` to the new list.
When done, just add the new list before the existing one.

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('#cursor');
const list = cursor.closest('ol');
const newList = document.createElement('ol');

const children = [...list.children];
for (const item of children) {
  if (item.contains(cursor)) {
    break;
  }
  newList.appendChild(item);
}

list.before(newList);
```

```html
<ol>
<li>item before 1</li>
<li>item before 2</li>
<li><span id="cursor">cursor</span></li>
<li>item after</li>
</ol>
```